# How can I create home page scrool like starbucks app home page

Tags: flutter

I am a junior developer.

I want to make a homepage scroll like the coffee application I mentioned, but I don't know how to search on the internet.

The first image pops up above the area just below the sliderappbar.There is an event like putting a container on top of the container.

I may not have explained it very well, so I want to share it video.

here the video:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xcGZggU_kQXvEjpDCa8iqkGCtytSUfoA/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `SliverAppBar` class for your use, which is a material design app bar provided by the dart.

[Youtube Link](https://youtu.be/R9C5KMJKluE)

[Flutter Dev Link](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/SliverAppBar-class.html)

Comment: I'm already using sliverappbar for appbar, there is a gray part under the appbar, I want to make that part. The first image rises above it when scrolling.

Comment: @thekavak please share your code snippets and the screenshot/video of what you have done!!

Comment: How can I share my code, that's why I'm asking because I really don't know please don't get me wrong, I have developed the whole homepage in widgets.

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:math' as math;
import 'dart:ui' as ui;
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart' show clampDouble;

class CustomFlexibleSpaceBar extends StatefulWidget {
  const CustomFlexibleSpaceBar({
    super.key,
    this.title,
    this.background,
    this.centerTitle,
    this.titlePadding,
    this.collapseMode = CollapseMode.parallax,
    this.stretchModes = const <StretchMode>[StretchMode.zoomBackground],
    this.expandedTitleScale = 1.5,
  });

  final Widget? title;
  final Widget? background;
  final bool? centerTitle;
  final EdgeInsetsGeometry? titlePadding;
  final CollapseMode collapseMode;
  final List<StretchMode> stretchModes;
  final double expandedTitleScale;

  @override
  // ignore: library_private_types_in_public_api
  _CustomFlexibleSpaceBarState createState() => _CustomFlexibleSpaceBarState();
}

class _CustomFlexibleSpaceBarState extends State<CustomFlexibleSpaceBar> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return LayoutBuilder(
      builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
        final FlexibleSpaceBarSettings settings = context
            .dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType<FlexibleSpaceBarSettings>()!;

        final List<Widget> children = <Widget>[];

        final double deltaExtent = settings.maxExtent - settings.minExtent;

                        final double t = clampDouble(
            1.0 - (settings.currentExtent - settings.minExtent) / deltaExtent,
            0.0,
            1.0);

                if (widget.background != null) {
          final double fadeStart =
              math.max(0.0, 1.0 - kToolbarHeight / deltaExtent);
          const double fadeEnd = 1.0;
          assert(fadeStart <= fadeEnd);
                              double height = settings.maxExtent;

                    if (widget.stretchModes.contains(StretchMode.zoomBackground) &&
              constraints.maxHeight > height) {
            height = constraints.maxHeight;
          }
          final double topPadding = _getCollapsePadding(t, settings);
          children.add(Positioned(
            top: topPadding,
            left: 0.0,
            right: 0.0,
            height: height,
            child: widget.background!,
          ));

                    if (widget.stretchModes.contains(StretchMode.blurBackground) &&
              constraints.maxHeight > settings.maxExtent) {
            final double blurAmount =
                (constraints.maxHeight - settings.maxExtent) / 10;
            children.add(Positioned.fill(
              child: BackdropFilter(
                filter: ui.ImageFilter.blur(
                  sigmaX: blurAmount,
                  sigmaY: blurAmount,
                ),
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.transparent,
                ),
              ),
            ));
          }
        }

                if (widget.title != null) {
          final ThemeData theme = Theme.of(context);

          Widget? title;
          switch (theme.platform) {
            case TargetPlatform.iOS:
            case TargetPlatform.macOS:
              title = widget.title;
            case TargetPlatform.android:
            case TargetPlatform.fuchsia:
            case TargetPlatform.linux:
            case TargetPlatform.windows:
              title = Semantics(
                namesRoute: true,
                child: widget.title,
              );
          }

                    if (widget.stretchModes.contains(StretchMode.fadeTitle) &&
              constraints.maxHeight > settings.maxExtent) {
            final double stretchOpacity = 1 -
                clampDouble((constraints.maxHeight - settings.maxExtent) / 100,
                    0.0, 1.0);
            title = Opacity(
              opacity: stretchOpacity,
              child: title,
            );
          }

          final double opacity = settings.toolbarOpacity;
          if (opacity > 0.0) {
            TextStyle titleStyle = theme.primaryTextTheme.titleLarge!;
            titleStyle = titleStyle.copyWith(
              color: titleStyle.color!.withOpacity(opacity),
            );
            final bool effectiveCenterTitle = _getEffectiveCenterTitle(theme);
            final EdgeInsetsGeometry padding = widget.titlePadding ??
                EdgeInsetsDirectional.only(
                  start: effectiveCenterTitle && !(settings.hasLeading ?? false)
                      ? 0.0
                      : 72.0,
                  bottom: 16.0,
                );
            final double scaleValue =
                Tween<double>(begin: widget.expandedTitleScale, end: 1.0)
                    .transform(t);
            final Matrix4 scaleTransform = Matrix4.identity()
              ..scale(scaleValue, scaleValue, 1.0);
            final Alignment titleAlignment =
                _getTitleAlignment(effectiveCenterTitle);
            children.add(Container(
              padding: padding,
              child: Transform(
                alignment: titleAlignment,
                transform: scaleTransform,
                child: Align(
                  alignment: titleAlignment,
                  child: DefaultTextStyle(
                    style: titleStyle,
                    child: LayoutBuilder(
                      builder:
                          (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
                        return Container(
                          width: constraints.maxWidth / scaleValue,
                          alignment: titleAlignment,
                          child: title,
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ));
          }
        }

        return ClipRect(child: Stack(children: children));
      },
    );
  }

  double _getCollapsePadding(double t, FlexibleSpaceBarSettings settings) {
    switch (widget.collapseMode) {
      case CollapseMode.pin:
        return -(settings.maxExtent - settings.currentExtent);
      case CollapseMode.none:
        return 0.0;
      case CollapseMode.parallax:
        final double deltaExtent = settings.maxExtent - settings.minExtent;
        return -Tween<double>(begin: 0.0, end: deltaExtent / 4.0).transform(t);
    }
  }

  bool _getEffectiveCenterTitle(ThemeData theme) {
    if (widget.centerTitle != null) {
      return widget.centerTitle!;
    }
    switch (theme.platform) {
      case TargetPlatform.android:
      case TargetPlatform.fuchsia:
      case TargetPlatform.linux:
      case TargetPlatform.windows:
        return false;
      case TargetPlatform.iOS:
      case TargetPlatform.macOS:
        return true;
    }
  }

  Alignment _getTitleAlignment(bool effectiveCenterTitle) {
    if (effectiveCenterTitle) {
      return Alignment.bottomCenter;
    }
    final TextDirection textDirection = Directionality.of(context);
    switch (textDirection) {
      case TextDirection.rtl:
        return Alignment.bottomRight;
      case TextDirection.ltr:
        return Alignment.bottomLeft;
    }
  }
}
```